# How to dismiss configurations from my lock screen in Android 6?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, lock-screens

I have just bought my first Android phone (Hauwei P8 lite). It came with Android 5.0, but it updated to Android 6.0.
I have configured it to have notifications on the lock screen, which I like. What is really bothering me is that I cannot dismiss them from the lock screen. Even if I swipe them to the right, it asks for my password and if I enter the password, the app that sued the notification is opened.

Is there any way to remove the notifications, clearing the lock screen, but not opening the app?

(By dismiss I mean that I want that single notification to go away, but I expect new notifications from that app to appear, so I do not want to change the configurations)